# T SQL anything after 2nd string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table `tblControl` with a column `SourceTableName`. This column contains SQL statements that look like:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(test, 'select * from ABC.tbl1')
```

How do I perform a `SELECT` on `tblControl` to just retrieve data after the 2nd 'from'? So using the above the desired outcome would be:

```
ABC.tbl1
```

I have tried the below to no avail:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING([SourceTableName], CHARINDEX('from', [SourceTableName]), LEN([SourceTableName])),
    PARSENAME(REPLACE([SourceTableName], 'from', ''), 1),
    SUBSTRING([SourceTableName], LEN([SourceTableName]) -CHARINDEX('from', REVERSE([SourceTableName])) + 2, LEN([SourceTableName]))
FROM 
    tblControl
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean data after the second `FROM`? Can you provide sample data and expected results please?

Comment: @Larnu I have.  The example data is the actual 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY...' and the expected result is ABC.tbl1

Comment: *"`SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY`"* isn't data, it;'s a SQL Statement.

Comment: @Larnu His column has that in single quotes `;-)`

Comment: @Larnu The table 'tblControl' contains a field called 'SourceTableName'.  This field contains text, that is yes, SQL statements but I need to extract jus the table name from the 2nd FROM.  Anyway, it has been resolved now.

Comment: Write a scalar Split function to be used like select dbo.fnSplit('from', 'select * from (select * from x))', 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A chained call to `CHARINDEX` gets you close to what you want:

```
WITH yourTable AS (
   SELECT 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(test, ''select * from ABC.tbl1'')' AS [Source TableName]
)

SELECT
    [SourceTableName],
    SUBSTRING([SourceTableName],
          CHARINDEX('from',
                    LOWER([SourceTableName]),
                    CHARINDEX('from', LOWER([SourceTableName])) + 4) + 5,
          LEN([SourceTableName])) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: I receive the error: The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: I updated my answer with something which at least would put you on the right track, but something like regex is what you really need here.  Sadly, SQL Server has no native regex support.